# jQuery mouseenter / mouseleave glitching

Tags: jquery, css

When I hover inside the box it fades out and in continuously. I don't know why or if that is only on my Browser (Siri), but you have to play with it a bit to realize my problem.

I'm trying to fade it out when I stay in the field, and fade it in again when I leave it.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sftLjk8/5/)

HTML:

```
<div class="ani-bounce-slow"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 200px; 
    width: 200px; 
    background-color: #3c3;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.ani-bounce-slow').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.ani-bounce-slow').fadeOut('slow');
});
$('.ani-bounce-slow').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.ani-bounce-slow').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: What are you wanting it to do?

Comment: added @kfreeman04208

Comment: makshh has the right solution. The reason your fiddle keeps fading in and out is because when your mouse enters the div you fade it out. This causes the div element be hidden, which in turn triggers your mouseout which fades your div element back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"fadeOut" fades the element then sets a class of display: none; which means it's no longer taking up space within the DOM. Because it's moved from under your mouse your mouseout event triggers causing it to fadeIn again.

if you animate the opacity. It will fadeOut but still take up space within the DOM so your mouse is still over the element. It won't fade in until you mouseout.

```
$('.ani-bounce-slow').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 800);
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 800);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9sftLjk8/7/

Comment: that's exactly what i want but i figured that out after the first answer ;)

Comment: It is a little bit different than adding class, because if you enter the mouse and leave couple of times (fast enough) animation will trigger more than one time, but it is also the solution :)

Answer (score 5):

When you hover over your box it fades out, so there is no box there anymore (therefore your function on mouseleave fires).

Better way is to use opacity in this case:

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 200px; 
    width: 200px; 
    background-color: #3c3;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.fade {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.ani-bounce-slow').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.ani-bounce-slow').addClass('fade');
})
$('.ani-bounce-slow').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.ani-bounce-slow').removeClass('fade')
});
```

OR:

```
$('.ani-bounce-slow').hover(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('fade');
});
```

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9sftLjk8/6/)

Comment: Yeah that's fine.. But when you go into my fiddle again and hover into my field and stay in.. It fades in again.. :|

Comment: I know that and I explained to you why it is happening :)

Comment: Ahh now I understand ^^ Sorry, i'm german so my english in not that good :S